# How to chain/compound matchers in Capybara?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I am trying to assert whether all results have either value A or value b. My set up is as follows:

```
def results 
 all('.results li')
end

def apply_filter(filter)
   filter_by(filter)
end

def have_product_type(type)
  have_selector('.type', text: type)
end
```

Now, I need to assert that all results are either of type A or type B.

I want to do something like this:

```
apply_filter('A')
apply_filter('B')
expect(results).to all(have_product_type('A').or have_product_type('B'))
```

Don't think compound matchers are supported in capybara yet. It works for one assertion at a time. For e.g this works:

```
expect(results).to all(have_product_type('A'))
```

I also tried normal RSpec matcher but then capybara chaining doesn't fit well with it.

For example this doesn't work either, because the methods are helper methods included in feature specs via config.include. I get undefined method error as the `have_product_type` method is in global namespace

```
expect(results.all {|result| result.have_product_type('A') or result.have_product_type('B')}.to be_truthy
```

How do I test for either condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compound matchers are supported in Capybara, as long as you ensure 'rspec/expectations' is required before Capybaras matchers.
One thing to note is that in your example of

```
expect(results).to all(have_product_type('A').or have_product_type('B'))
```

Capybaras waiting behavior could make this part of you test very slow.  This would be because the have_product_type('A') will wait up until Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for a matching 'A' element to appear for every element in results, so if most actually match 'B' the delay could be long.  In that case you probably want to instead check for a change on the page that indicates the filters have been applied, and after that pass `wait: false` to the have_selector matchers used in your expectation (or execute the expectation inside a `using_wait_time(0){ expect ... }` block.

Note: you could also implement what you're trying to by just using the regex version of the :text option with something like

```
expect(results).to all(have_product_type(/^(A|B)$/'))
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I used the regex version for now. I will try the compound matchers and see if that works well with wait: 0. Thanks.